# Why am I getting "Variable "entry" does not exist"

Tags: templating

This seems random to me, as it was not a problem until today...

I am getting the template error `Variable "entry" does not exist` with a reference to line`06` below.

This is a template for social icons that I `include` on each page.

The code template below is included in my site template.  It works on the index page, but it works no where else other than an actual entry (post) page.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ entry.url }}" class="social-link"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up your code example a bit? This is pretty difficult to read. (ie: properly indent code, remove irrelevant tags)

Comment: Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide some fallbacks for pages that don't have en entry like this

```
{{entry.title|default('here is your fallback')}}
```

You can do this multiple times, chaining fallbacks. Inside the fallback you can provide a global or maybe set a page at the top of your template like this:

```
{% set entryFallback = craft.entries.id(1).first() %}
{{entryFallback.title}}
```

**Edit**

In your specific case where you just want to return the url from the page you are on to create a twitter share button, you can just get the current Url:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{craft.request.url}}" class="social-link"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```